# How to determine which route was matched for a controller#action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Consider the example in the note for this guide on [routing and singular resources](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) Both of these would be directed to 'photos#index', but are different contexts.

1. /users/1/photos (might list a user's photos)
2. /photos (list all users' photos)

I want to give the user different options depending on which route was followed to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to assign this issue.

### 1st way

In the `users_controller.rb`

```
before_action :set_user, only: [:photos]

def photos
    @photos = @user.photos
    render "photos/index"
end

private

@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

In `routes.rb` you need to add this route,

```
resources :users do
   get "photos", on: :member
end
```

### 2nd way

In `photos_controller.rb`
     before_action :set_user, only: [:photos]

```
 def index
   unless @user.nil?
      @photos = @user.photots
   else
      @photos = Photo.all
   end
 end

 private

 def set_user
   if params[:user_id].present?
      @user = User.where(params[:user_id]).first
   end
 end
```

Comment: I don't like the first way very much and appears that it would lead to a RESTful conflict (hiding a resource within another). I think I'll be using the 2nd way you proposed but instead of checking for the presence of a param I will pass in a new param (labelled something like :scope or :context). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, I'd make /users/1/photos an action off users controller instead.  However, if you really want to do what you say there, you could check for presence of the user_id param on the photos controller index and fashion your finder appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

For example you can [validate](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/routing-specs) route match with `rspec`, something like the following:

```
expect(:get => "/users/1/photos").to route_to(
  :controller => "photos",
  :user_id => "1",
)
```